# How to solve segmentation fault (core dumped) while reading SCF files?

Tags: perl, bioperl

I got segmentation fault (core dumped) error when I try read SCF file.

I'm using Bio::SCF module in perl and just followed the example from "https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::SCF".

The code is as below ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Bio::SCF;

my $scf = Bio::SCF->new('filename.scf'); # line A
or 
tie %scf, 'Bio::SCF', "filename.scf"; # line B
```

I hoped one of the lines read the scf file but, neither worked and just sending the "segmentation fault (core dumped" message.

What can I do?
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Please provide the input file, the output of `perl -V`, the version of the `io_lib`/`staden-read` library.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, 
I want to provide output of "perl -V" but seems too long.
Anyway, the version of perl is v5.28.1. if you need more information please let me know.
The version of "io_lib" is 1.14.8 and "staden" is 2.0.0b11-2016. 
Also I don't know how to provide scf file to you. 
It's just normal sanger sequencing data, which opens well at software "UGENE". 
Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out a way to give us the info we need [so we can reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve#Reproducible). Maybe ask your colleagues for help.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not really an answer, since you didn't provide much information, but it's the best I can do presently...)

[Bio::SCF](https://metacpan.org/release/Bio-SCF) is a compiled library (notice the .xs file), so it could have easily broken if something changed in your perl install and BIO::SCF wasn't recompiled.  I would suggest, as a first step, to reinstall BIO::SCF and make sure that its tests pass (check the log for the cpan client you are using).